# How to filter out certain values during aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do an aggregation to find minimum Latitude in my index.

```
post myIndex/_search?pretty=true
{
  "aggs": {
    "min_lat": {
      "min": {
        "field": "latitude"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query returns all the records, plus the smallest latitude.

I would like the aggregation to ignore records where Latitude 0 or less (e.g. southern hemisphere).  But the records themselves should still be returned.

How do I do that?  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filter aggregation before your min aggregation.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "positive_lat": {
      "filter": { "range": { "latitude" : { "gt": 0 } } },
      "aggs" : {
        "min_lat": {
          "min": {
             "field": "latitude"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-range-query.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html

Comment: @monnon you forgot the `latitude` inside `range` :)

Comment: Woups! My bad, Thank you @deerawan

Comment: Thank you.  I also wanted a query that returns everything that's not sitting right on the equator and I did the following...    "aggs": {
    "positive_lat": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": { 
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "latitude": 0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }, 
      "aggs" : {
        "min_lat": {
          "min": {
             "field": "latitude"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }.  It works, but what about from a standpoint of performance? Is it best construction perf wise?